# Which version of `gcc` supports the `--no-undefined` switch?

Tags: python, c, gcc, linker, nifti

I am trying to compile `pynifti` package from source (long story involving Anaconda Python distribution).

After running `make`, I receive the following error:

```
 gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘--Wl,--no-undefined’
```

Indeed, the manual (`man gcc`) contains no information about `--no-undefined` switch. My version of `gcc` is 4.8.5. Also, I can not find the `no-undefined` option in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Index.html#Option-Index

However, from [Force GCC to notify about undefined references in shared libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356168/force-gcc-to-notify-about-undefined-references-in-shared-libraries) I infer that it is a valid switch at least for some version of `gcc`.

Comment: Do: s/--Wl/-Wl/

Comment: thanks, it is working now; I hate to fix third-party code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This switch is a [linker option](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.16/ld/Options.html) for `ld`. It is not directly part of `GCC` but it is only encapsulated in a `-Wl` option to be passed to the linker (you seem to have `--Wl` which is wrong).

Edit:
Yugr deserves part of the credit as he pointed out the incorrect `--Wl` option!

Comment: Unfortunately @Yugr have not provide an answer which I may either accept or upvote. :-(

Comment: @abukaj Gerhardh's answer was mostly complete so that's fine.