# C++ compiles and links with pointer to undefined function

Tags: c++, linker, static-assert

This code:

```
void undefined_fcn();
void defined_fcn() {}

struct api_t {
    void (*first)();
    void (*second)();
};
api_t api = {undefined_fcn, defined_fcn};
```

defines a global variable `api` with a pointer to a non-existent function. However, it compiles, and to my surprise, links with absolutely no complaints from GCC, even with all those `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic` flags.

This code is part of a shared library. Only when I load the library, at run-time, it finally fails. How do I check, at library link-time, that I did't forget to define any function?

---

Update: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356168/force-gcc-to-notify-about-undefined-references-in-shared-libraries) mentions the same problem, and the answer is the same: `-Wl,--no-undefined`. (by the way, I guess this could even be marked as duplicate). However, according to the accepted answer below, you should be careful when using `-Wl,--no-undefined`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This code is part of a shared library.

That's the key. The whole purpose of having a shared library is to have an "incomplete" shared object, with undefined symbols that must be resolved when the main executable loads it and all other shared libraries it gets linked with. At that time, the runtime loader attempts to resolve all undefined symbols; and all undefined symbols must be resolved, otherwise the executable will not start.

You stated you're using `gcc`, so you are likely using GNU `ld`. For the reason stated above, `ld` will link a shared library with undefined symbols, but will fail to link an executable unless all undefined symbols are resolved against the shared libraries the executable gets linked with. So, at runtime, the expected behavior is that the runtime loader is expected to successfully resolve all symbols too; so the only situation when the runtime loader fails to start the executable will indicate a fatal runtime environment failure (such as a shared library getting replaced with an incompatible version).

There are some options that can be used to override this behavior. The `--no-undefined` option instructs `ld` to report a link failure for undefined symbols when linking a shared libraries, just like executables. When invoking `ld` indirectly via `gcc` this becomes `-Wl,--no-undefined`.

However, you are likely to discover that this is going to be a losing proposition. You better hope that none of the code in your shared library uses ***any*** class in the standard C++ or C library. Because, guess what? -- those references will be undefined symbols, and you will fail to link your shared library!

In other words, this is a necessary evil that you need to deal with.

Comment: As mentioned in the comment in the other answer, the problem is not that it's a dynamically linked shared library. I tried it, and everything I said in my question is valid when compiling/linking directly the final executable.

Comment: Except that the reason you're not getting a link failure on the shared library is precisely what I explained in my answer, and if you want to know how to trigger a link failure for an undefined reference from your shared library, the instructions are in my answer, but, as I explained, you will figure out that you don't really want to do that, actually.

Comment: Actually, I tried it, and I can call `malloc` and `free` under `-Wl,--no-undefined`. Maybe it's because glibc is linked statically?

Comment: And by the way, I think `-Wl,--no-undefined` worked for me, thanks!

Comment: I'm wondering if you understand his answer though, or if I'm misunderstanding it myself. 

The entire point of dynamic linking is that the library doesn't even need to be physically present on the machine until you execute the program. So the linker has to let it through at link time, unless it's statically linked.

Comment: I get it, but I'm not linking my library against any other dynamic library, and the code that loads my library does so using `dlopen`, so I don't think there will be a problem here.

Comment: You must be explicitly linking your shared library with the standard C++ and C library. This will resolve all references to the standard libraries from your shared libraries. As long as you explicitly link your shared libraries with all your dependencies, this approach will work.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have the compiler tell you whether you forgot to define the function in that implementation file.  And the reason is when you define a function it is implicitly marked `extern` in C++.  And you cannot tell what is in a shared library until after it is linked (the compiler's linker does not know if the reference is defined)

If you are not familiar with what `extern` means.  Things marked `extern` signal external linkage, so if you have a variable that is `extern` the compiler doesn't require a definition for that variable to be in the translation unit that uses it.  The definition can be in another implementation file and the reference is resolved at link time (when you link with a translation unit that defines the variable).  The same applies for functions, which are essentially variables of a function type.

To get the behavior you want make the function `static` which tells the compiler that the function is not `extern` and is a part of the current translation unit, in which case it must be defined `-Wundefined-internal` picks up on this (`-Wundefined-internal` is a part of `-Werror` so just compile with that)

Comment: Thanks. I understand that I can't get help at compile-time because the function might be defined in another translation unit. But why can't I get help at *link* time? Why doesn't the linker realize that I'm trying to get a pointer to a non existing object?

Comment: @fonini my guess is that the linker doesn't know what the shared object contains until after its linked (because its dynamically linked)

Comment: Actually, I tried it, and GCC still doesn't complain if I put the code in my question directly in the executable :\ If I don't try to actually *call* the undefined function, everything goes smoothly

Comment: @fonini What did you try?  It should complain if you did it correctly, an undefined reference should be flagged by the linker.  If it's not, then it's because you didn't use the function anywhere (just declared it)!

Comment: I didn't *call* the function anywhere, but I initialized a global variable with a pointer to this (non-existing) function. The code obviously doesn't run, but it compiles and links fine.

Comment: @fonini Thats strange, my code exits with an error when I make it point to an undefined function  see https://ideone.com/Iw7PvX

Comment: You're right, I was defining both functions. Oops. (but this is in the executable; in the shared library, it still accepts the undefined function)