# Load Multiple Library in C program

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I dont know if this is a bad question, but I am having some problem of an undefined symbol when my program is run.

I have more than 20 dynamic libraries,

When I run my program that loads my library

```
 void *encode_func  = dlopen("lib_9_3.so", RTLD_LAZY  );
```

It returns error as undefined symbol,

All its symbol depends upon those 20 dynamic libraries
Can I load all those dynamic libraries in my C program ???

EDIT::

```
if ( encode_func == NULL)
    {
            fprintf(stderr, "dlopen failed: %s\n", dlerror());
            return 1;
    }
```

Code is fine,
dlerror is returning

```
 dlopen failed: ./lib_9_3.so: undefined symbol: sip_getExtensionParamCountFromFromHdr
```

These symbols are present in my 20 dynamic libraries,
I found this out by doing  "nm"

One more thing, these undefined symbols are not system specific.

Can I load all those dynamic libraries in my C program ???

Comment: What error exactly?  Is `lib_9_3.so` something you built and can modify?

Comment: `dlopen()` doesn't return a (pointer to a) function, so this code looks fishy...

Comment: @JohnZwinck , Yea Its something I built and I can modify.

Comment: I suggest you build your `lib_9_3.so` with `-Wl,--no-undefined` to prevent it building with unsatisfied dependencies.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356168/force-gcc-to-notify-about-undefined-references-in-shared-libraries